# Aggregating data by hour using R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I have data of the form:

```
[1] "Mon Feb 01 09:11:55 +0000 2016" "Mon Feb 01 09:12:11 +0000 2016" ""
[4] "Mon Feb 01 09:14:25 +0000 2016" "" "Mon Feb 01 09:15:40 +0000 2016"
```

and I want to plot it using R.

I want to do an hourly plot of counts so all those between 9 and 10AM would be counted in one bucket and so on. The data will be over several days but date is unimportant just hour. I might also want to change hour to 30 minutes say.
I've tried various things but I'm a little out of my depth and would be very grateful for a few basic steps to get it to work.

I've tried:

```
str <- strptime(dt, "%a %b %d   %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz = "GMT") 
# head(str,3)
( dt.gmt <- as.POSIXct(str, tz = "GMT") )
format(dt.gmt, tz = "EST", usetz = TRUE)
hms <- format(dt.gmt , format = "%H:%M:%S")
hms<-as.numeric(hms)
head(hms,3)
hms <- table(cut(hms, breaks="hour"))
```

which gives the error:

```
Error in breaks + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I've also tried:

```
aggdata <-aggregate(hms, by=(hms), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

which gives:

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) :   'by' must be a list
```

Comment: `hms` is no longer an object that can be cut by time-ish specifications. If you only care about counts-per-hour why not just `hr <- format(dt.gmt , format = "%H")` and `table(hr)`?

Comment: Thanks! That's looking good, is it possible to use the same thing for say 20 minute periods instead of hours? And it there a simple way of plotting it?

Comment: can you link to a data file?

Comment: Sorry, I have been away. My data is publicly available racist tweets, I have tried to redact them but I apologise if any offensive material is still there:  [data](http://dropcanvas.com/afjn6).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just tried this, May be this can help you

```
dt <- c("Mon Feb 01 09:11:55 +0000 2016", "Mon Feb 01 10:12:11 +0000 
         2016","Mon Feb 01 09:21:55 +0000 2016" )
df <- data.frame('time' = dt, 
             'id' = c(1, 3, 2))
df$time <- as.POSIXct(gsub("^.+? | \\+\\d{4}","", df$time),
                                                          format = "%B %d %X %Y")
df$time  <- as.POSIXlt(df$time)
df$hour <- format(df$time, format = '%H')
df
pivot <- aggregate(df$id, by = list(df$hour), FUN = length)
pivot
```